# How to use different font name in UITableViewCell UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uifont

I want to use different Font name in a `UILable` in `UITableViewCell`. I try with a lot of examples like:

```
    Cell.cellSectionLabel.text = [self.textsInTableSection objectAtIndex:0];
    Cell.cellSectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesInTableSection objectAtIndex:0]];
    Cell.cellSectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0f/255.0f green:56.0f/255.0f blue:62.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [Cell.cellSectionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];
    Cell.cellSectionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

It is not working. The Font name actually read the default Font of my device. Because if I use some different Font name here `[Cell.cellSectionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:16]];`, it doesn't change any thing. It remain the same. How can I use different font name in this case?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Follow this checklist and make sure you are setting correct properties to correct non-nil instances http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please remove the last line of your code and try again.
Cell.cellSectionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

According to your code you are setting font to Helvetica 16 
& again changing it back to System font
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I was using this line `[Cell.cellSectionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];` from the beginning. But it is not working at all. That's why I set `UIFontSize` separately here in this line `Cell.cellSectionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];`. And it's working. I just wondering how does it can recognize a Font just for putting it's name inside `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];`. I think there should be something proper way. Which I am not following here.

Comment: // Call the method when required to find fonts added to app
-(void)getFontFamiliesWithFontNames {
    for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", family);
        
        for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
        {
            NSLog(@"  %@", name);
        }
    }
}    

You can use the above code to NSLog all the System fonts.
And can use any one in your code.

Comment: I have to insert a particular Font name from the 2nd `for loop` in a `NSString` variable and then when I use that variable as font, it's working. It makes sense now. Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting it back to the system font. Delete this line:

```
Cell.cellSectionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
```